# Codeacademy Javascript ...And the good! / right output but codeacademy doesn't like it

Tags: javascript

working through the tutorial. I wrote a piece of code to return all numbers in range and replace those %3 && 5% or both with a string, but for whatever reason codeacademy returns an error (Oops, try again. It looks like you printed out the wrong number of items).

Here is my code, hopefully you can enlighten me where the problem is:

```
function fizzBuzz(num){
  var i = 1;

  while(i <= num){

    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log("FizzBuzz");
      i++;

    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      console.log("Fizz");
      i++;

    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log("Buzz");
      i++;

    } else {
      console.log(i);
      i++;
    }
  }
}
console.log(fizzBuzz(20));
```

Comment: You should give us more hints about the expected output

Comment: To answer, we would need to know the exact requirements of the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

While I will not comment on the quality of your `fizzBuzz` function (because it won't be glowing with positive comments...) you are calling `console.log(fizzBuzz(20))`, which - since there is no `return` statement in that function - will log `undefined` to the console, which is one item more than Code Academy expects.

Just call `fizzBuzz(20);`